# SQL Server: hierarchy of permissions for schema?

Tags: sql-server, schema, permissions

We have several databases under development and I would like to start using SQL Server schemas for permission management and logical grouping of database objects. Under Schema Properties there is explicit permissions like

```
Alter
Control
Delete
Execute
...
```

What is the hierarchy of these permissions? The idea is to grant `Control` for admin AD group, and give developer AD group some rights that allow them to do their work (ddl, read, write). What rights should be given for developers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quick answer: For developers, you can GRANT CONTROL on that schema.

Background:

- To see what can be `GRANT`ed: [GRANT Schema Permissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187940.aspx)
- To see what each permission means: [Permissions Naming Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191291.aspx)

The intersection of these two give the schema permission meanings:

- `CONTROL` implies the rest and is the highest permissions of any securable
- `SELECT, DELETE, INSERT, UPDATE` is DML on objects in that schema
- `EXECUTE` to run scalar UDFs and Stored Procedures in that schema
- `ALTER, REFERENCES` is DDL (CREATE, ALTER, DROP) on objects in that schema
- `VIEW DEFINITION` lets folk see the code and definitions

Except for CONTROL, these are mostly orthogonal to each other: folk can `EXECUTE` code or `SELECT`, from a view but not see the definition (`VIEW DEFINITION`) of these.

You also have the database and server permissions which are implied higher up then CONTROL on schemas: see [Permissions Hierarchy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191465.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, if I give CONTROL for developers, can they make changes for permission e.g of this schema?

Comment: @jrara: Only if you use "WITH GRANT OPTION" I think. I normally allow developer db_owner in their own databases so haven't tried it. I can't do any tests either just now.