# Setting Select Permission on 100+ tables in a database

Tags: sql-server-2012, t-sql, permissions

I got the 'Select permission denied' error for some of my tables in a database.

In `MS SQL Server 2012`, setting `Select` Permission on 1 table is easy. I just right click on the `table > Properties > Permissions > Select the User/Role` and tick the `Select` Permission in the 'Explicit' tab below.

But I want to do that for over a 100 tables. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the tables were in a user defined schema, say `data` and not the default `dbo` then you can GRANT select on the schema

```
GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA::Data TO MyRoleOrUser
```

I regard this as best practice. It also means any new tables *inherit* `SELECT` permisisons from the schema and don't need explicit grants

- [SQL Server: hierarchy of permissions for schema?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6920/sql-server-hierarchy-of-permissions-for-schema/6921#6921)
- [Decision criteria on when to use a non-dbo schema vs a new Database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11101/decision-criteria-on-when-to-use-a-non-dbo-schema-vs-a-new-database/11105#11105)
- [Schema design - best practices?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4075/schema-design-best-practices/4109#4109)

Answer (score 0):

Use `GRANT` statement with tables delimited by comma like below.

```
Grant select on tbl_1, tbl2, tbl3, tbl4, ...., tb1100 to [MyRole];
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of alternatives.

You could set the Select permission to the Schema that owns the tables. (dbo?)

```
grant select on schema :: dbo to myUser --or myDBRole
```

or use query to generate the 100 grant select statements and execute.

```
SELECT 'grant select on ' + TABLE_NAME + ' to myUser' --or myDBRole
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME
```

Comment: Don't forget about schema (also [see this](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views)).

Answer (score 0):

Run this query:

```
select 'Grant select on ['+t.name+'] to [MyRole];' from sys.tables as t;
```

Copy the output to a new SSMS tab, edit as required and submit for processing.